# R - Sample consecutive series of dates in time series without replacement?

Tags: r, random, time-series, sample, lubridate

I have a data frame in R containing a series of dates. The earliest date is (ISO format) 2015-03-22 and the latest date is 2016-01-03, but there are two breaks within the data. Here is what it looks like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

date_data <- tibble(dates = c(seq(ymd("2015-03-22"),
                                  ymd("2015-07-03"),
                                  by = "days"),
                              seq(ymd("2015-08-09"),
                                  ymd("2015-10-01"),
                                  by = "days"),
                              seq(ymd("2015-11-12"),
                                  ymd("2016-01-03"),
                                  by = "days")),
                    sample_id = 0L)
```

I.e.:

```
> date_data
# A tibble: 211 x 2
   dates      sample_id
   <date>         <int>
 1 2015-03-22         0
 2 2015-03-23         0
 3 2015-03-24         0
 4 2015-03-25         0
 5 2015-03-26         0
 6 2015-03-27         0
 7 2015-03-28         0
 8 2015-03-29         0
 9 2015-03-30         0
10 2015-03-31         0
# … with 201 more rows
```

What I want to do is to take ten 10-day long samples of continous dates from within that time series *without replacement*. For example, a valid sample would be the ten days from 2015-04-01 to 2015-04-10 because that falls completely within the `dates` column in my `date_data` data frame. Each sample would then get a unique (non-zero) number in the `sample_id` column in `date_data` such as `1:10`.

To be clear, my requirements are:

1. Each sample would be 10 *consecutive* days.
2. The sampling has to be *without* replacement. So if `sample_id == 1` is the 2015-04-01 to 2015-04-10 period, those dates can't be part of another 10-day-long sample.
3. Each 10-day-long sample *can't* include any date that's not within `date_data$dates`.

At the end, `date_data$sample_id` would have unique numbers representing each 10-day-long sample, likely with lots of `0`s left over that were not part of any sample (and there would be 200 rows - 10 for each sample - where `sample_id != 0`).

I am aware of `dplyr::sample_n()` but it doesn't sample *consecutive* values, and I don't know how to devise a way to "remember" which dates have already been sampled...

What's a good way to do this? A `for` loop?!?! Or perhaps something with `purrr`? Thank you very much for your help.

UPDATE: Thanks to @gfgm's solution, it reminded me that performance is an important consideration. My real dataset is quite a bit larger, and in some cases I would want to take 20+ samples instead of just 10. Ideally the size of the sample can be changed as well, i.e. not necessarily 10-days long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky, as you anticipated, because of the requirement of sampling without replacement. I have a working solution below which achieves a random sample and works fast on a problem of the scale given in your toy example. It should also be fine with more observations, but will get really really slow if you need to pick a lot of points relative to the sample size.

The basic premise is to pick n=10 points, generate the 10 vectors from these points forwards, and if the vectors overlap ditch them and pick again. This is simple and works fine given that `10*n << nrow(df)`. If you wanted to get 15 subvectors out of your 200 observations this would be a good deal slower.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

date_data <- tibble(dates = c(seq(ymd("2015-03-22"),
                                  ymd("2015-07-03"),
                                  by = "days"),
                              seq(ymd("2015-08-09"),
                                  ymd("2015-10-01"),
                                  by = "days"),
                              seq(ymd("2015-11-12"),
                                  ymd("2016-01-03"),
                                  by = "days")),
                    sample_id = 0L)

# A function that picks n indices, projects them forward 10,
# and if any of the segments overlap resamples
pick_n_vec <- function(df, n = 10, out = 10) {
  points <- sample(nrow(df) - (out - 1), n, replace = F)
  vecs <- lapply(points, function(i){i:(i+(out - 1))})

  while (max(table(unlist(vecs))) > 1) {
    points <- sample(nrow(df) - (out - 1), n, replace = F)
    vecs <- lapply(points, function(i){i:(i+(out - 1))})
  }

  vecs
 }

# demonstrate
set.seed(42)
indices <- pick_n_vec(date_data)

for (i in 1:10) {
  date_data$sample_id[indices[[i]]] <- i
}

date_data[indices[[1]], ]
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>         dates sample_id
#>        <date>     <int>
#>  1 2015-05-31         1
#>  2 2015-06-01         1
#>  3 2015-06-02         1
#>  4 2015-06-03         1
#>  5 2015-06-04         1
#>  6 2015-06-05         1
#>  7 2015-06-06         1
#>  8 2015-06-07         1
#>  9 2015-06-08         1
#> 10 2015-06-09         1
table(date_data$sample_id)
#> 
#>   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10 
#> 111  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

#### marginally faster version

```r
pick_n_vec2 <- function(df, n = 10, out = 10) {
  points <- sample(nrow(df) - (out - 1), n, replace = F)
  while (min(diff(sort(points))) < 10) {
    points <- sample(nrow(df) - (out - 1), n, replace = F)
  }
  lapply(points, function(i){i:(i+(out - 1))})
}
```

Comment: Thank you @gfgm, what an insightful answer and solution! Just tried doing it with getting 20 subvectors and it is still running as I write this. Therefore there is a chance it might not work well in my real use case (bigger dataset but also with bigger number of samples (sometimes 20+!)), and I'll edit the question to mention this. I wonder if there's a way to optimise the function so that it takes one sample at a time while "remembering" it so that the next iteration will be sampling from a smaller dataset? Would that even improve performance...???

Comment: hey @hpy, yeah if you try to take 20 samples from the toy example you posted it will run forever, as there are only 211 observations in `date_data` and you need to sample 200 of them. The odds of picking the exact 20 starting points that result in a solution are infinitesimal! But if you needed to pick 20 points from a data.frame of 1000 observations it will most likely succeed on the first try! what matters is the ratio of points to observations, not the number of points per se (within limits of course)

Comment: also, per your suggestion yes I could probably re-write to resample more selectively. But first try it out and see if it works for you on an example with more data (bearing in mind that you want the ratio of (n points)/nrow(df) to be small)

Comment: btw just edited function to let you pick number of consecutive days `out`

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I just went to my real data, which has 565 dates to sample from. But it's broken up a lot more, so some segments are less than 10-days meaning I have less than 565 dates available.

Comment: That said, I managed to get the number of samples up to 15 without big problems, 20 still takes forever. And thanks for adding the `out` option! The current solution is therefore enough for my current needs, but as my dataset continues to grow and my sampling needs change I might need a more optimised solution in the future.... Marking as solved, though I might repost to /r/rstats if you don't mind. :) You also reminded me that I should really learn reprex (are there good tutorials?), what a useful tool!

Comment: @hpy yeah reprex is awesome. I posted a marginally faster version -- but this won't make a serious difference if you need a lot of segments from a small data.frame. I suspect the mathematicians have an algorithm for sampling segments -- if they tell you post an answer!

Comment: Great thanks!! And will definitely post if I learn of an alternative solution.